# Trouble with 5 Digit Unicode in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with the larger unicode images in JQuery and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

If I set the line to be

```
if ( IsItOverFlowing() ) { $HM.text("\u2302"); }
```

will show a nice little house (PERFECT), but

```
if ( IsItOverFlowing() ) { $HM.text("\u1F3A5"); }
```

shows '15 instead of a movie camera?  Charset is UTF-8.

Any ideas re the above, or in general how to get the >4 character Unicode to play nice with jQuery `.text()`

Answer (score 2):

Javascript internally only supports UTF-16.

Because this is an extended 32-bit UTF character (not in the "Basic Multilingual Plane") you need to insert the "UTF-16 surrogate pair", which is helpfully provided on the same page that you linked to:

0xD83D 0xDD13
i.e.

```
$('#myId').text('\ud83d\udd13');
```

You can put the character there directly, as a quoted string, e.g.

```
$("#myID").text('');
```